# Is it possible to change the window title bar of your installer using Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, titlebar

Is it possible to change the title bar of your installer using Inno Setup?

By default is:

```
AppName=My Program
```

and when you run the setup in the title bar appears:

> Setup - My Program

Is it possible to hide the word *"Setup"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the InnoSetup installation folder there's a `default.isl` file, open that file in a text editor, find the `SetupWindowTitle` entry and change the right side from `Setup - %1` to only `%1`. Also repeat the process for additional languages you use in the setup, you'll find the matching '.isl' files in the 'Languages' folder.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It will work, but it is wrong. If you need to override the default messages in Inno Setup then you should use the `[Messages]` section of your setup script file like Jens A Koch suggested. Copy the relevant line from `default.isl` into your script's `[Messages]` section and edit as required. You can still use the `%1` style variables.

Comment: @Nicolas - *"This answer is wrong."* - I don't think a solution that satisfies the problem qualifies as wrong, perhaps you mean "it would be wrong to implement this solution.*

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer does satisfy the problem, and perhaps it is not actually _wrong_. It depends on what what the problem is: To change the title for _all_ setups created by this Inno Setup configuration then you should modify `default.isl` but if you only want to change the title for a _specific_ setup then you need to add a `[Messages]` section to your script instead.

Answer (score 22):

Add the following lines to your InnoSetup script file:

```
[Messages]
// define wizard title and tray status msg
// both are normally defined in innosetup's default.isl (install folder)
SetupAppTitle = Setup YourApplicationShortName
SetupWindowTitle = Setup - YourApplicationName YourApplicationVersion
```

This will modify the "title bar" and the "app title" in the tray.

I would suggest not modifying the default configuration in `/innosetup/default.isl`,
like Sertac Akyuz pointed out. Think of this file as fallback config.
If you don't define a setting, then the setting is taken from `default.isl`.
Just modify your file; not the default settings!

Comment: If you need to use additional languages in your setup you should copy every entry in this section and localize it by adding prefix with the language's internal name followed by a period. For example: `russian.SetupAppTitle=Установка`. See InnoSetup help `[Languages] section` to find out language's internal name.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the caption of the main form, try this:

```
[code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
    WizardForm.Caption := 'Welcome to My Program';
end;
```

It, unfortunately, will not change the "Setup" caption on the taskbar.  Since this is a delphi application, you would need access to the Application global variable to change this effortless, but this object is not exposed to pascal script, and I don't know any way to do it directly.  I think you can follow the @satuon advice to change it using windows messages.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution (also if you want to make your iss setup file be correctly compilable on any computer) is to redefine the certain language string in `Messages` section **after** the definition of the Languages file.

For example:

```
[Languages]
Name: de; MessagesFile: compiler:Languages\German.isl
;Name: en; MessagesFile: compiler:Default.isl

[Messages]
WizardReady=I am ready.
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple no Codes

```
[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=Your Programme Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using Pascal scripting. Inno Setup allows you to call SendMessage and PostMessage from your Pascal section. Try to use that to send a WM_SETTEXT message to your window.

Comment: This seems kinda hackish, no? An indirect solution that would probably work, mind you, but still not ideal.