# AppVersion not showing on InnoSetup window title bar

Tags: inno-setup

I was researching a way of putting the app version number on the setup window title of my InnoSetup installer and I found this question: [Add Version to SetupWindowTitle of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57883316/8133067).

On the comments section of the question, @MartinPrikryl stated:

> The %1 in SetupWindowTitle is replaced with AppVerName, which defaults
> to "AppName version AppVersion". So SetupWindowTitle actually contains
> AppVersion. You must have something wrong in your script.

But in my case the `AppVersion` property was always set and the version number never showed up on the window title. I thought it had something to do with the language package I was using (*Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl*) but it turns out it's not.

I've made a simple test script to reproduce the behavior:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Test
AppVersion=1.0
VersionInfoVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName=C:\Test\
```

I'm using Inno Script Studio version 2.2.2.32 with Inno Setup Compiler version 5.5.9.
When I compile that simple test I get this result:

[image: InnoSetup test installer window title]

No `AppVersion` on window title, just the `AppName`.
What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it was just an InnoSetup version issue (thanks to @MartinPrikryl [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63017762/#comment111439599_63017762)!). I was using InnoSetup compiler version 5.5.9, but with the current 6.0.5 version it works.

Actually, this feature was added on 5.6.0 version (2018-06-08):

> [Inno Setup 5.6 Revision History](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm)
>
> **Change in default behavior:** If [Setup] section directive `DisableWelcomePage` is set to `yes` (which it is by default), then the title of the wizard now includes `AppVerName` instead of `AppName`, in other words: it now includes the version number of the application. If `WindowVisible` is set to `yes` this applies to the background window instead.

Anyway, in my case I was not totally happy with the result because my installer manages other installers and it's called something like '**Setup Manager**'. With the new InnoSetup version the installer window title becomes '**Setup - Setup Manager version 1.0.0.5**'.

From *'Default.isl'* file, with default English language:

```
[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=Setup - %1
```

Actually I use portuguese language and the real installer name is '**Instalador MyCompany**', so the text on the window title becomes '**Instalador MyCompany versão 1.0.0.5 - Instalador**'.

From *'Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl'* file, with Brazilian Portuguese language:

```
[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=%1 - Instalador
```

In both language scenarios the additional word ("Setup" or "Instalador") is too much, so, I changed the `SetupWindowTitle` property only to `%1`:

```
[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=%1
```

And now it's fine:

[image: InnoSetup updated test window title]

Other source:
[Is it possible to change the window title bar of your installer using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076935/8133067)